# At which step should i18n and l10n happen? At the beginning or at the end?

Tags: web-applications, localization, internationalization

As I am not English, and my mother tongue and my country's formal language are different, I have to deal with (at least) 3 different languages all the time!!

Now, my question:
When writing a web app, should one do the i18n and l10n part at the beginning of the process or after everything is done(and the app is working properly)?

I think it should be done at the end. This way the software is ready and the developer's mind is not busy with making the software. On the other hand, many parts of the UI has to change based on the direction(ltr or rtl).
Any ideas are extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internationalization(i18n) has to be part of development. If you wait until the end, you will need to rewrite parts of the code. Consider the following items:

- Allowing locale specific number and date formatting
- Externalizing all textual resources
- Creating a design which will handle text expansion well
- Allowing  metric vs imperial

... (see this [link](http://www.emreakkas.com/internationalization/10-internationalization-tips-for-developers-i18n-checklist) for more)

All these items require a different approach during design and development. It is a big (but very common) mistake to say "lets figure English out first, we will worry about the rest later". This approach is almost certain to cause more money, time and frustration hours to be spent when the time for localization comes.

I18N is simply a set of best practices that you need to apply during development. Even if you are not planning to localize your app, you should develop with I18N in mind.

Comment: English is perhaps the worst base for localisation, so if you start on English you will, even with those 4 listed adaptations, end up with assumptions in your text that are English assumptions.  E.g. the classic "Add %s"; works in English but almost certainly not in any other language.  I would also say start L10N as early as possible.  Using pseudolocalisation using a tool like [podebug](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/podebug) means you can see what parts are not working for localisation. Translating them yourself will expose bad assumption in the source.